# Port Forwarding with Archer C7

Tags: port-forwarding

I am attempting to forward 3 ports to my local machine in order to use the Golem token network.

I went to my ethernet adapter settings, and created a static IP address from the public IPv4 address found in my cmd ipconfig /all.

Say the IPv4 was like 111.111.1.1xx I then created a static IP address where xx where in the range my router supported.

I used the same values from the ipconfig for the Subnet Mask and default gateway. for the DNS server I used 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4.

Under my router I added the 3 ports that I want to forward, TCP, and the IP address as the static one I had set in my ethernet adapter settings, but installing a port checker shows that all 3 ports are still closed.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have anything listening on the 3 ports?

Comment: I’m sorry I’m a little confused by what you mean, like any active programs waiting for info to be sent to those ports?

Comment: Exactly. If nothing is listening then port checker will show the ports as closed.

Comment: Ah okay. I will run the program I am having issues with and try again. Initially I thought the program wasn’t running because the ports were closed, I may have to dig into the logs.

Comment: @DavidPostill I called my ISP and I had to go into my modem settings to port forward those ports to my router. Now its working, and like you mentioned the program had to be opened. If you put that as an answer I will gladly accept.